# adding style to html tag based on dir scss

Tags: html, sass, dart-sass

in my nuxt projeect i'm using dart-sass with a file called constants to determine the value of a variable called $dir that controls the functionality of some mixins. i want to modify the value of the $dir variable if the html tag has a dir attribute.
what i have right now (which isn't working) is this

```
$dir: "ltr";

html {
  &[dir="ltr"] {
    $dir: "ltr" !global;
  }
  &[dir="rtl"] {
    $dir: "rtl" !global;
  }
}
```

and my html tag has the dir attribute with a value of "ltr" but what happens is that the variable keeps getting overwritten as "rtl" even though the value of dir is "ltr"

also if i change the above code to this

```
$dir: "ltr";

html {
  &[dir="rtl"] {
    $dir: "rtl" !global;
  }
  &[dir="ltr"] {
    $dir: "ltr" !global;
  }
}
```

the value of $dir becomes "ltr" which means that both styles are applied and are just overriding each other so what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to think about global vars at that point. Use your code basis as switch to write different rtl/ltr-styles using the unique mixins. You only have to forward the local variable each time to another stylesheet just by importing the file.

That idea woul look something like that:

```
//######> file: main.scss

// ## general mixin
@mixin background($dir){
    @if($dir == 'ltr'){
        background: green;
    }
    @if($dir == 'rtl'){
        background: red;
    }
}



// ###### main styles

html {
    &[dir="ltr"] {
      $dir: 'ltr' ;
      @import 'ltrStyles';
    }
    &[dir="rtl"] {
      $dir: 'rtl' ;
      @import 'rtlStyles';
    }
}

//######> file: _rtlStyles.scss

.rtlClass {
    @include background($dir);
}


//#####> file: _ltrStyles.scss

.ltrClass {
    @include background($dir);
}


//######> result:

html[dir=ltr] .ltrClass {
  background: green;
}
html[dir=rtl] .rtlClass {
  background: red;
}
```

*( Just as example to think forward ... )*

Comment: i'm trying to avoid import as much as possible .. also since this variable is within a sas s module that has all my mixins so i usually "@use" that module everywhere which would significantly increase my css size if i have imports in it .. i'll try to do that import in my main style file though and just import the module within each direction-specific style file

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured out another way to change the variable globally.
the sass-loader allows you to add additional data that are passed as variables globally within the config file (in my case nuxt.config). and since the config file is a js file i was able to determine the site's language from within the file and switch the $dir with an if condition after all.
so i made the following changes:

```
$dir: 'ltr' !default;
```

at every file that needed that variable and then i adjusted the '@use' in my bundle file as following

```
@use "helpers" as h with(
 $dir: $dir
);
```

and the same for every component or page i used my helper module in.
this means that i have to add h. before every variable or mixin i use after the import but i'm fine with that
still i don't understand why the global overwrite didn't work